# Concatenation of variable and locator in feature file is not working

Tags: karate

print 'Confirmation Number = ', getConfirmationNumber
Above gives result as - print] Confirmation Number =   10201020
But below line is not working where concatenation of variable and locator in feature file. Locator

- waitFor("[data-confirmation-number='" + getConfirmationNumber + "']").click()
  The above locator is unique and found in DOM and correct one like "[data-confirmation-number='10201020']"

But gives error as below:

01: waitFor("[data-confirmation-number='" + getConfirmationNumber + "']").click()
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: waitUntil (js): failed after 10 retries and 50106 milliseconds

- com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions.retry(DriverOptions.java:517)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.waitUntil(WebDriver.java:476)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions.waitForAny(DriverOptions.java:700)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.Driver.waitFor(Driver.java:237)
- .:anonymous(Unnamed:1)

Please let me know if I am missing something or doing incorrect.

Comment: clearly some mistake in your locator. hard for anyone to help without access to your app